# Android : How to know the active polyline in maps API V2

Tags: android, google-maps

I have application to make polyline in android maps. I check the aktive polyline with onMapLongClickListener. I check the arraylist where I store path of polyline. the problem, when I have two separated polyline and I want to check the closest path, I only can check it with the last polyline I made, I want to check with the first polyline, but it's not working. what wrong with my code?

```html
package com.evy;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions;

import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
 GoogleMap map;
 private boolean isNewPoly=false;
 ArrayList<LatLng> points;
 PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
 String list;
 MarkerOptions markerOptions;

 @Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
  
  SupportMapFragment mapFragment=(SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
  map=mapFragment.getMap();
  
  Button stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stop);
  Button start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.start);
  
  map.setOnMapClickListener(new OnMapClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    if(isNewPoly){
     markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Position").snippet("Latitude: "+point.latitude+" , "+"Longitude: "+point.longitude);
     map.addMarker(markerOptions);
     points.add(point);
     polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
     polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
     polylineOptions.width(3);
     polylineOptions.addAll(points);
     map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
    }
    else {
     
     cek(point);
     
    }
   }
  });
  
  map.setOnMapLongClickListener(new OnMapLongClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onMapLongClick(LatLng poin) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    //if(isNewPoly){
     cek(poin);
    //}
   }
   
  });
  
  start.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    isNewPoly=true;
   }
  });
  
  stop.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

   @Override
   public void onClick(View arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             isNewPoly = false;
   }
  });
 }
 
 public void cek(LatLng poin){
  float mindist = 0;
  int pos=0;
  Double lat1=poin.latitude;
  Double lng1=poin.longitude;
  
  for(int i=0; i<points.size();i++){
   Double lat=points.get(i).latitude;
   Double lng=points.get(i).longitude;
   float[] distance = new float [1];
   Location.distanceBetween(lat1, lng1, lat, lng, distance);
   if(i==0){
    mindist=distance[0];
   }
   else if(mindist>distance[0]){
    mindist=distance[0];
    pos=i;
   }
  }
  LatLng ne = points.get(pos);
  Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "marker terdekat "+ne+" "+mindist, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  MarkerOptions markerOptions = new MarkerOptions().position(poin).title("Position").snippet("Latitude: "+lat1+" , "+"Longitude: "+lng1);
  map.addMarker(markerOptions);
  points=new ArrayList<LatLng>();
  points.add(ne);
  
  points.add(poin);
  polylineOptions = new PolylineOptions();
  polylineOptions.color(Color.BLUE);
  polylineOptions.width(3);
  polylineOptions.addAll(points);
  map.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
  
 }
 
 @Override
 public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

  // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
  getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
  return true;
 }

 @Override
 public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
  // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
  // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
  // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
  int id = item.getItemId();
  if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
   return true;
  }
  return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
 }
}
```

thats the code I made. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want a way to keep track of the different polylines entered into the map. `map.addPolyline(polylineOptions)` will return a Polyline object. You can store these Polylines in an array for later comparison. `getPoints()` can be called on each Polyline object to get the LatLng points.

Comment: can you explain with a code? I want to check the near point of polyline with click on map. if there is a point that near with the current location, I want it make new polyline. do you understand what i mean? sorry for my bad english